# Creating Mobile and Web App. What to do first?

Tags: android, python, django, mobile, web

I'm creating an android app, using Android Studio and at the same time making a web version of the said app using django. Is it better to make a python web app in django with the database and all first. So in the mobile app, i wont need to store data anymore, im just gonna grab the data from the web to show in the mobile app. If so, how do i do getting data from web and show it to android app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way is to make a web service which returns a json which you can consume on your mobile app and store it if needed offline.